# How to expand x² ? Is that possible?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I have uploaded the steps in link provided.
I don't understand what just happened to x² in solution attached. Is there a Taylor series expansion for x²? I don't think so. Can you please explain the **expansion of x²** in attached solution.
[Click here to see solution of above question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i11e5.png)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the solution, $x^2$ is **already** a Taylor series: every polynomial is. If you like, though, you can expand it in the usual way about $0$: if $f(x)=x^2$, then

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n=\frac2{2!}x^2=x^2\,,$$

since all of the derivatives except the second are $0$ or evaluate to $0$ at $x=0$. If you insist on writing out every term of the series, you have

$$x^2=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\,,$$

where

$$b_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=2\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

The solution then simply adds this Maclaurin series to the one for $e^x$:

$$\begin{align*}
e^x+x^2&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac1{n!}+b_n\right)x^n\\
&=1+x+\left(\frac1{2!}+1\right)x^2+\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac1{n!}x^n\\
&=\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}x+\frac3{2!}x^2+\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac1{n!}x^n\,,
\end{align*}$$

so it is the exponential generating function for the sequence $\langle a_n:n\ge 0\rangle$, where $a_2=3$, and $a_n=1$ if $n\ne 2$.